# Invoke native android activity in Titanium

Tags: titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

For my Titanium applications, i am writing a custom native android module that includes an android jar consisting few android activities that i want to reuse.How can i invoke those activities from my application.

Answer (score 2):

This comes straight from the Titanium Android Module Development Guide https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Android+Module+Development+Guide

> To use your module in a Titanium Mobile app, follow these steps:
>
> Copy the module zip to the root of the Titanium app, or to the root of
>   the system Titanium installation In the application's tiapp.xml, add
>   the following XML inside :
>
> ```
> <!-- $MODULE_VERSION should be the same as "version" in the module manifest -->
> <modules>
>   <module version="$MODULE_VERSION">$MODULE_ID</module>
>   <!-- For example, if we were adding the calc module: -->
>   <module version="0.1">org.appcelerator.calc</module>
> </modules>
> ```
>
> Use the require function to load the module in the app's code,
>   Example:
>
> ```
> var Module = require('$MODULE_ID');
> // For example, to load the calc module:
> var Calc = require('org.appcelerator.calc');
> ```
>
> The next time the app is Launched or built, the module should be
>   included with the application